# Batch/Cmd Read for content from one file and update in another

Tags: script, batch-file

I should be able to do this but I think the brain has had enough for the day :~(

I have a file in the following format (already containing the values):

```
 Server=\\servername\sharepath

 Username=server\user

 Password=passwdval
```

I need to read the values and insert those values into the following file (as shown below):

```
<SHARE>\\servername\sharepath</SHARE>
<DOMAIN>server</DOMAIN>
<USER>user</USER>  <UPWD>passwdval</UPWD>
```

This HAS to be done with a batch/cmd file.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're not a script-writing service, but we're happy to help you when you've tried a few things and come up against something you can't puzzle out yourself.

Comment: Thanks guys actually got it yesterday with a few if statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply echo your text and escape all the `<>` with a caret `^<` and `^>`.
Read your input file and split at the equal sign with a for /f into `%%A/%%B`.
You have to split Username into DOMAIN and USER with another for /f `%%C/%%D`.

```
:: Q:\Test\2017\09\14\SU_1250115.cmd
@Echo off
Set "FileIn=SU_1250115.txt"
Set "FileOut=SU_1250115.xml"

( For /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%A in ("%FileIN%") Do (
    If /i "%%A"=="Server" Echo:^<SHARE^>%%B^<SHARE^>
    If /i "%%A"=="Username" for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=\" %%C in ("%%B") Do (
        echo ^<DOMAIN^>%%C^</DOMAIN^>
        echo ^<USER^>%%D^</USER^>
    )
    If /i "%%A"=="Password" echo ^<UPWD^>%%B^<UPWD^>
  ) 
) >"%FileOut%"
```

Sample output:

```
> type SU_1250115.xml
<SHARE>\\servername\sharepath<SHARE>
<DOMAIN>server</DOMAIN>
<USER>user</USER>
<UPWD>passwdval<UPWD>
```